# Why `resolutions` does not be supported in package.json same as bower.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

As we know, the **resolutions** is used to solve `Dependency versions to automatically resolve with if conflicts occur between packages.` in `bower.json`.

After searching this [package.json page](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), I did not find the `resolutions` is supported in it. Is there any reason why `resolutions` should not be here or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It's not in the package.json specification because it's part of the bower.json specification, which is different. bower.json files are included in packages you install with bower, not npm. So if I say:

```
bower install jquery
```

Then `bower.json` will be in ./bower_components/jquery directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yarn does have the `resolutions` feature though, see doc [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-flat)

> yarn install --flat
>
> Only allow one version of a package. On the first run this will prompt you to choose a single version for each package that is depended on at multiple version ranges. These will be added to your package.json under a resolutions field.